# preg_match_all show me diff in loca server

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

`/(\W|^)some(\W|$)/ui` - find 2 word in string in online editor

when i try in local find 3 word

```
string: "some text for some word in somes"
```

what problem i have in my local server?

Comment: What are you trying to match? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$subject ='some text for some word in somes';

echo (preg_match_all('~\bsome\b~', $subject));
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://viper-7.com/nm0vgR)

Comment: i find where i have problem but can't fix it

Comment: in my local server results is different.